# How to use the pictureSize to set height and width?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm creating a project with expo, to capture photos and save them in the device's gallery. Where these photos must be the same height and width regardless of the device.

So, I want to define a height and width of the image captured by the camera, so that the result looks like this [resize example](https://snack.expo.dev/sttIIbvonY).

For this, I thought about using the [pictureSize](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#picturesize) type to set the `height` and `width` of the image captured by the camera.

I tried using ***react-native-image-crop-picker*** and ***react-native-image-resizer*** package and haven't been able to make any progress.

My project code is available at: [CameraApp](https://github.com/AbadeDiego/CameraApp.git)

Does anyone know how I can do this implementation?

Comment: I dont know what you consider to be the dimensions of an image but anyhow i do no see you setting any resolution.

Comment: You set to `100%` and `undefined` so you set no resolution. And if you set a ratio you also do not set a resolution as a ratio is not a resolution.

Comment: Height and width would be the resolution. But you are not setting them.

Comment: Well a full resolution image can still have the wanted ratio. Where is it that you do not see the wanted ratio?

Comment: `app that will take a photo with the same resolution` AND `to set all saved photos to a ratio of 9:16.` Well that just does not match as resolution is something different then ratio. Strange that after 20 hours we still dont know what you want.

Comment: Hi @blackapps thanks for the explanations. I've edited the question and added what I've done so far.